# test function is not recognized as a global function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I followed a JavaScript unit testing tutorial at acadamind.com in that tutorial instructor used Vitest for demonstrations and the reason they mentioned using Vitest instead of Jest was Jest needed some extra configuration to work with the latest JavaScript syntax.

After doing my own research about unit testing I realized industry demand unit testing skills with the Jest. So I followed another tutorial for learning unit testing with Jest and React Testing Library (RTL).

I created a brand new TypeScript project with Create React App (CRA) and followed the instructions in that tutorial and everything went well. The instructor mentioned that Jest and RTL are supported out of the box with CRA.

After studying unit testing I tried to apply that knowledge and write some tests with my application, which was created some time back, and recently we updated it to React Scripts 5.  In that application, I check `node_modules` folder, and Jest is there as a dependency. But I have noticed that the following packages are not listed in the `package.json` file in my project, so I installed them:

```
@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
```

After that, I noticed my new project has this file in the `src` folder so I have copy pasted this file as well.

**setupTest.ts**

```
// jest-dom adds custom jest matchers for asserting on DOM nodes.
// allows you to do things like:
// expect(element).toHaveTextContent(/react/i)
// learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

When I tried to run when I tried to write my first unit test I noticed that VS Code doesn't recognize this `test` function as a global function and indicates an error and then I try to run the test script and I am getting this error

```
 Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /home/pathum/Documents/tagd/node_modules/axios/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    > 1 | import axios from 'axios';
        | ^
      2 | // config
      3 | import { HOST_API } from '../config';
      4 |

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils/axios.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/hooks/useRefresh.tsx:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/hooks/useAxiosPrivate.tsx:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/contracts/contract-form/new-contact-person.tsx:12:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/contracts/contract-form/parties.tsx:15:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/contracts/contract-form/contract-form.tsx:9:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/contracts/contract-form/contract-form.test.tsx:2:1)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.398 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Seems I need to do some configurations for Jest to work properly in the application. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Install the necessary dependencies: npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-typescript and npm install --save-dev jest-cli typescript

Create a new file in the root of your project called jest.config.js and add the following content to it:

```
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    testMatch: ['**/*.test.ts'],
};
```

Add a new property called "jest" to the "scripts" section of your package.json file and set it to the following: "jest --config jest.config.js --coverage". This will tell Jest to use the configuration file you just created and also generate a coverage report.

Create a new file in the root of your project called tsconfig.test.json and add the following content to it:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./test-dist"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.test.ts"
    ]
}
```

Finally, you can run your tests with npm run jest.
You also need to make sure that you are using import statement correctly in your tests. You should use import statement to import functions, classes, and variables from other modules, but you should use require statement to import modules that are not written in TypeScript.